# How to display the Python Dictionary key and value pairs in HTML part of the python code

Tags: python, html, jinja2, python-3.7

I am working on this code, I am doing web scraping from a website and getting the values and assigning it to the dictionary variable. Then, I am sending an email which contains the key and value pairs in the HTML format.

I got stuck in the displaying dictionary key and value pairs in the HTML part. I tried sending email but email is sent successfully to the target but, the dictionary values in HTML are getting printed and I am getting the code which is mentioned in the  as it is.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
me = "examplefrom@gmail.com"
you = "exampleto@gmail.com"


def webScrape():
    dict={}
    URL="Website URL"
    page=requests.get(URL)

    soup=BS(page.content, 'html.parser')
    results=soup.find_all('div', class_="blog-posts clear")
    for results_element in results:
        title_elem = results_element.find_all('h2', class_='home-title')
        link_element=results_element.find_all('a', class_="story-link", href=True)
        for index,(title,link) in enumerate(zip(title_elem, link_element)):
            dict[str(title.text)]=str(link['href'])
    return dict


dictionary_values=webScrape()



msg = MIMEMultipart()
password = "password"
msg['Subject'] = "Your Webscrape Data"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     
        {% for key, value in dictionary_values.iteritems() %}
        <br/>
       <h3><a href={{key}}>{{value}}</a></h3>
       <br/>
       {% endfor %}

  </body>
</html>
"""


part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(part2)
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
server.starttls()
server.login(msg['From'], password)

server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

server.quit()

print("Send Successfully")
```

Comment: Please explain what is the problem. It is not clear.

Comment: I am not able to display dictionary_value  content ie, key and value pairs inside HTML content

Comment: do not use 'dict' as a variable name. change it. before you return from `webScrap` print the return value.

Comment: The syntax within `html` looks vaguely like the Jinja2 template engine. You'd need to plug in that template engine to do something with `html`.

Comment: ok...got it and why the values is not getting in the html

Comment: @AKX, How to plugin Jinga2 in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using Jinja2 template syntax, but you haven't actually imported or used Jinja2 here, which you can do like this:

```
from jinja2 import Environment

jinja_env = Environment(autoescape=True)

template = jinja_env.from_string("""
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    
       {% for key, value in dictionary_values.items() %}
       <br/>
       <h3><a href={{key}}>{{value}}</a></h3>
       <br/>
       {% endfor %}

  </body>
</html>
""")

html = template.render(dictionary_values=dictionary_values)
```

Comment: I tired this but i am getting the email..but its printing only values part of the dictinary and not key part of the dictionary

Comment: Within your link you only print the value – the key ends up in the `<a href>`.

Comment: I did this --> <a href={{key}}><h3>{{value}}</h3></a> but still the same output

Comment: Are you sure your scrape results are correct, then? The template definitely works.

Comment: i am facing another issue also...The mail contains the link from the scrap but when i click that link its getting redirected to only this link (http://red/)

Comment: i am pasting the scrape results which i tried for a hackernews website below

Comment: {'Red Team — Automation or Simulation?': 'https://thehackernews.com/2020/09/red-team-penetration-test.html', 'FinS
py Spyware for Mac and Linux OS Targets Egyptian Organisations': 'https://thehackernews.com/2020/09/finspy-malware
-macos-linux.html'}

Comment: i am able to paste only this due to character constraints in the comment section

Comment: That paste says the URL is the `value`, not the `key`...

Comment: Yes the URL is the value and the key is the title content

Comment: And your template attempts to put the _key_ in the `href`.

Comment: I got it...Now its resolved....thank you very much @AKX

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am marking this question as answered

Comment: You Nailed It @AKX